# jcarousel out of position when not at 100% in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I use Sorgilla jcarousel, just wondering can anyone spot something obvious as to why only in Google Chrome, when I zoom in or out, not at 100% the positioning of the carousels are completely off.
Im not sure what specific code to post but here are the 2 carousels being called. both have the same problem.
Im assuming its something to do with the pixels not adjusting for resize or something, but it isnt an issue in other browsers.

Any help would be great thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    start: 2, // Configuration goes here
    wrap: "circular",
    scroll: 1,
    auto:7
});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#top-carousel').jcarousel({
    start: 2, // Configuration goes here
    wrap: "circular",
    auto: 12,
    scroll: 1

});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the workaround that works fine for me.
This is not the best solution, you can definitely try to improve it.
Here is how you can change your code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var animation = $.browser.safari ? null : "normal";
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    start: 2, // Configuration goes here
    wrap: "circular",
    scroll: 1,
    auto:7,
    animation: animation,
        itemLoadCallback: {
            onBeforeAnimation: function (instance) {
                if ($.browser.safari) {
                    var itemPos = instance.first;
                    var pageWidth = instance.container.width();
                    var expectedItemPos = pageWidth * (1 - itemPos);
                    instance.container.prevObject.animate({ "left": expectedItemPos + "px" });
                }
            }
        }
});
});
```

The code above is used for left to right carousel.
Additinal info about jcarousel configuration you can find [here](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration)